# How to set custom y axis Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts

So, I tried using [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) on my project, and it all work fine, but there is one thing I can't make it done, which is set custom y axis. What the tutorial said was about using `count`. While I need some kind of this code:

```
@foo = Bar.select("SUM(payment_amount)").group(:payment_date)
```

So I need that the y axis consist of cumulative amount of those data, how should I do this with **Chartkick**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Bar.group(:payment_date).sum(:payment_amount)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for back to this case just now. Really thanks sir. That really work, so I know more about it way to worked, really thanks. Now time to go advance on it :D